# Troubleshooting UART communication between nano 33 ble sense r2 and Adafruit Feather 32u4 with LoRa Radio Module

Tags: communication, uart, feather, arduino-nano-33-iot

I've tried connecting the gnd's for both the boards and have connected rx to tx and vice versa in both the boards. I've powered both by batteries, and I'm trying to get sensor data from the nano, and trying to send it to the feather via UART, and long distance away using the Lora capabilities of the Feather.

I've loaded this program in the nano:

```cpp
/*
Including libraries
*/
//Accelerometer{
#include "Arduino_BMI270_BMM150.h"
//Accelerometer}
//Temperature and humidity{
#include <Arduino_HS300x.h>
//Temperature and humidity}
//Pressure{
  #include <Arduino_LPS22HB.h>
//Pressure}

/*
Creating variables for sensors
*/
//Acceleration variables{
float x, y, z;
//Acceleration variables}
//Temperature and humidity variables{
float temperature;
float humidity;
//Temperature and humidity variables}
//Pressure variables{
float pressure;
//Pressure variables}

void setup() {

/*
Setting up sensors
*/
Serial1.begin(9600);
//Accelerometer{
  if (!IMU.begin()) {
    Serial1.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
    int i = 0;
    Serial1.println("Trying again\n");
    while (!IMU.begin()){
      if(i>0){
        Serial1.print(" Failed\n");
      }
      Serial1.print("Try number ");
      Serial1.print(i);
      i++;
      delay(1000);
    }
    Serial1.print("Passed\nOn attempt number ");
    Serial1.print(i);
    Serial1.print("\n");
  }
//Accelerometer}
//Temperature and humidity{
if (!HS300x.begin()) {
  Serial1.println("Failed to initialize humidity temperature sensor!");
  int i = 0;
    Serial1.println("Trying again\n");
    while (!HS300x.begin()){
      if(i>0){
        Serial1.print(" Failed\n");
      }
      Serial1.print("Try number ");
      Serial1.print(i);
      i++;
      delay(1000);
    }
    Serial1.print("Passed\nOn attempt number ");
    Serial1.print(i);
    Serial1.print("\n");
}
//Temperature and humidity}
//Pressure{
if (!BARO.begin()) {
  Serial1.println("Failed to initialize pressure sensor!");
    int i = 0;
    Serial1.println("Trying again\n");
    while (!BARO.begin()){
      if(i>0){
        Serial1.print(" Failed\n");
      }
      Serial1.print("Try number ");
      Serial1.print(i);
      i++;
      delay(1000);
    }
    Serial1.print("Passed\nOn attempt number ");
    Serial1.print(i);
    Serial1.print("\n");
}
//Pressure}
}

void loop() {
  /*
  Read sensor data into the variables
  */
  //Read acceleration{
  if (IMU.accelerationAvailable()) {
    IMU.readAcceleration(x, y, z);
  }
  //Read acceleration}
  //Read temperature and humidity{
  temperature = HS300x.readTemperature();
  humidity = HS300x.readHumidity();
  //Read temperature and humidity}
  //Read pressure{
  pressure = BARO.readPressure();
  //Read pressure}
  
  /*
  Print the sensor data to Serial1 (hopefully implement sending this data to the lora feather, which will radio it to a distant arduino)
  */
  Serial1.print("\nAcceleration (x, y, z): ");
  Serial1.print(x);
  Serial1.print(", ");
  Serial1.print(y);
  Serial1.print(", ");
  Serial1.print(z);
  Serial1.print("\nTemperature: ");
  Serial1.print(humidity);
  Serial1.print("\nHumidity: ");
  Serial1.print(humidity);
  Serial1.print("\nPressure: ");
  Serial1.print(pressure);
  delay(1000);

}
```

I've loaded this program in the transmitting feather:

```cpp
/* The program for the feather1 to take information from nano 33 ble sense rev2 and radio it to  where the feather2 
** will communicate to the ground station's program todisplay the data in a user friendly manner, and will display results
*/
#include <RH_RF95.h>

// LoRa settings
#define RFM95_CS 8
#define RFM95_RST 4
#define RFM95_INT 7
#define RFM95_FREQ 915.0

RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RFM95_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  if (!rf95.init()) {
    Serial.println("LoRa init failed. Check your connections.");
    while (1) ;
  }
  rf95.setFrequency(RFM95_FREQ);
  rf95.setTxPower(23, false);
  Serial.println("LoRa Transmitter Ready!");
}

void loop() {
  static uint16_t messageCount = 0;
  String input;
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    input += c;
  }
  if (input.length() > 0) {
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    input.getBytes(buf, input.length() + 1);
    rf95.send(buf, input.length() + 1);
    rf95.waitPacketSent();
    Serial.println("Sent message #" + String(messageCount) + ": " + input);
    messageCount++;
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

I've got this program in the receiving feather:

```cpp
/* The program for the feather2 to recieve information from feather1 ** and will communicate to the ground station's program todisplay the data in a user friendly manner, and will display results
*/

#include <RH_RF95.h>

// LoRa settings
#define RFM95_CS 8
#define RFM95_RST 4
#define RFM95_INT 7
#define RFM95_FREQ 915.0

RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // Wait for serial port to be available 
  /* The infinite while loop above not needed if you're not using rx/tx for sending 
  ** the recieved radio data to your program or are using some other method to 
  */
  pinMode(RFM95_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  if (!rf95.init()) {
    Serial.println("LoRa init failed. Check your connections.");
    while (1) ;
  }
  rf95.setFrequency(RFM95_FREQ);
  rf95.setTxPower(23, false);
  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver Ready!");
}

void loop() {
  if (rf95.available()) {
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len)) {
      Serial.print("Received: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
    } else {
      Serial.println("LoRa receive failed");
    }
  }
}
```

I have been able to establish UART communication between two Unos before, but I'm unable to find out why it isn't working in this case. I can confirm it isn't working because the Serial monitor for the recieving feather (feather2) only shows this:

```
17:52:39.840 -> LoRa Receiver Ready!
```

Why this is happening, and any potential fixes for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see 32U4 I'd expect the Serial is used for native USB serial (CDC). If you want to use usart on pins 0 and 1, you'd have to use Serial1 instead.

Nano 33 BLE is the same, it has native USB and you are correctly using Serial1 for accessing serial pins 0 and 1 (however nRF52840 can use any pins).